# Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using reverse accessors vs direct queries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I happen to be working on an existing project, that uses a lot of direct queries instead of reverse accessors.  Take the following contrived example:

```
class Student(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    school = ForeignKey(School, ...)

class School(Model):
    def get_daves(self):
         ...
```

The 'get_daves' method on School could be implement in either of the following ways:

```
def get_daves(self):
    return self.student_set.filter(name='Dave')

def get_daves(self):
    return Student.objects.filter(school=self, name='Dave')
```

And the project I'm working on, seems to have a lot of the latter, whereas I'd typically use the first option.

Aside from being more succinct, and arguably clearer as to what you're intending, are there any other reasons to use the reverse accessor method, over querying the Students directly.

I assume under the hood they result in equivalent DB queries, and the same amount of work constructing the models when the queryset is iterated.  I just wanted to make sure there isn't a good reason to go ahead and start changing all of the instances of the direct queries in the project as I find them.

Comment: Both produce the same SQL query, yes.

Comment: I also feel, based on personal evidence, that in django projects you will find a lot of the latter, so it's a valid point to adhere to the community standards

Comment: I personally find `.filter(school=self)` to be a bit of an awkward expression, `self > relation_set > filter` looks more natural imo